# CodeIgniter - How to style table properly? (Cell Width)

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter, css-tables

I have no idea how to do that and it is very frustrating.

I've tried this, but it doesn't do anything.

```
table td
{
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 200px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

And also maybe it is possible to somehow style every column separately. I'm using Code Igniter table helper module so I have little access over each td, tr etc...

Okey, I fixed my problem using 
table

```
{
    word-break: break-all;
}

td
{
    padding-left: 6px;
    padding-right: 6px;
    max-width: 500px;
    min-width: 100px;
}
```

Still I will probablt build my own HTML Table class to make things much easier and more controllable in future.

Comment: What does your table look like now, versus how you want it to look?

Comment: What does this have anything to do with codeIgniter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table class is somewhat limited in what it can and can't do as you've probably noticed.

If you need anything more than the basic table (you can set even/odd row classes in CI), then you will likely need to create your own table class/create your own table output (it's not exactly difficult).

Also, I'm pretty sure CI's table generator will force a width, unless you specify otherwise with a custom template

```
$tmpl = array (
'table_open'   => '<table border="0" width="XXX" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">',
```

As a result, even if you style the TD's, the **table** width will still take priority if you like and confine the TDs.

A table width of 100% will still fill all the available width and force the TD's to be sized that way, even if your css says otherwise.

The only way I know around this is to either ommit the  width from the `<table>` entirely which could be unpredictable, or set the table to be as wide as `200 * number of columns`, and everything will display nicely.

(If you add `inline-block` to the TD you can force the width to 200px, but table td's, by default are `display:table-cell`)

Answer (score 0):

From [CI documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/table.html):

> If you would like to set an individual cell's tag attributes, you can use an associative array for that cell. The associative key 'data' defines the cell's data. Any other key => val pairs are added as key='val' attributes to the tag:

```
$cell = array('data' => 'Blue', 'class' => 'highlight', 'colspan' => 2);  
$this->table->add_row($cell, 'Red', 'Green');
```

**Sample code**
Lets suppose you have a table in wich you want to have two last columns with edit and delete links/icons... have you seen something like this before?

You could have some css code like this:

```
.table_cell_bgimage{
    background-size: 20px;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

 .edit_table_cell_bgimage{
    background-image: url("path_to_img/edit.jpg");  
}

.delt_table_cell_bgimage{
    background-image: url("path_to_img/delt.jpg");  
}
```

Your php / CI code, then, will look like this:

```
$this->load->library('table');
$edit_cell = array('class' => "table_cell_bgimage edit_table_cell_bgimage");
$delt_cell = array('class' => "table_cell_bgimage delt_table_cell_bgimage");

$table_data = array(
    array('v1', 'v2', 'v3', 'v4', 'v5', $edit_cell, $delt_cell),
    array('v1', 'v2', 'v3', 'v4', 'v5', $edit_cell, $delt_cell),
    array('v1', 'v2', 'v3', 'v4', 'v5', $edit_cell, $delt_cell),
    array('v1', 'v2', 'v3', 'v4', 'v5', $edit_cell, $delt_cell),
    array('v1', 'v2', 'v3', 'v4', 'v5', $edit_cell, $delt_cell),
    array('v1', 'v2', 'v3', 'v4', 'v5', $edit_cell, $delt_cell)
); 

$data['table'] = $this->table->generate($table_data);
```

... and the resulting table will look like this:

[image]

Dont forget to set table width 100% writing something like this:

```
$tmpl = array ( 'table_open'  => '<table style="width:100%">' );
$this->table->set_template($tmpl);
```

Enjoy.